# Pegando a última posição no banco

Tags: php, cakephp

Preciso pegar a última linha de uma coluna usando CakePHP.

Estou tentando assim:

```
$idAtual = $this->Albun->find('all', array('fields' => 'codigo'));
```

Só que ele está retornando todas as linhas. Como conseguir só a última?

Comment: Tente dar um `order by desc` no id e retorne somente um linha com o `limit`. Essa é uma possibilite existem outras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que adicionar ordem decrescente e trocar o `all` por `first`

```
 $idAtual = $this->Albun->find('first', array('fields' => 'codigo', 'order' => array('codigo DESC')));
```

Mais infos:

[BookCakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

poderia fazer algo assim

caso inserido no momento

`echo $this->Albun->getInsertID();`

insira o código aquipegando o ultimo inserido na base para a tabela

`echo $this->Albun->getLastInsertID();`